# Transaction for bulk queries one or nothing

Tags: vb.net

Target is to every query to be executed and inserted or nothing, if at least one failed everything should be rolledback. I implemented as below. Could someone take a look and tell me whether this is correct implementationfrom vb.net and sql point of view. As i told if at least one would failed nothing should be inserted to db.

```
#Region "Final articel insert to database"
    Public Function ProcessArticle(artikel As ArticlesVariations) As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean = True
        Dim strcon = New AppSettingsReader().GetValue("ConnectionString", GetType(System.String)).ToString()

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(strcon)
            '-- Open generall connection for all the queries
            connection.Open()
            '-- Make the transaction.
            Dim transaction As SqlTransaction
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

            Dim newArticleRowID As Integer = 0
            Dim articleIndex As Integer = 0
            Try
                For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Artikel) In artikel.collection
                    Dim ckey As Integer = kvp.Key
                    articleIndex = kvp.Key              'save article key
                    Dim data As Artikel = kvp.Value

                    '-- Insert aricle to Article's table (tbArtikel) and get inserted row id to use it in other queries
                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbArtikel (Nummer, Name, Gewicht, EANBarcode, Vater, Hohe, Breite, Tiefe, Lange, Preis, FK_Geschaft_ID, 
                                            FK_SubKategorie_ID, FK_SubSubKategorie_ID, FK_Hersteller_ID) VALUES (@Nummer, @Name, @Gewicht, @EANBarcode, @Vater, 
                                            @Hohe, @Breite, @Tiefe, @Lange, @Preis, @FK_Geschaft_ID, @FK_SubKategorie_ID, @FK_SubSubKategorie_ID, @FK_Hersteller_ID);Select Scope_Identity()", connection)
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        cmd.Connection = connection
                        cmd.Transaction = transaction
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nummer", data.Nummer)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", data.Name)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gewicht", data.Gewicht)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EANBarcode", data.EANBarcode)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vater", data.Vater)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hohe", data.Hohe)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Breite", data.Breite)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tiefe", data.Tiefe)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lange", data.Lange)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Preis", data.Preis)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Geschaft_ID", data.FK_Geschaft_ID)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_SubKategorie_ID", data.FK_SubKategorie_ID)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_SubSubKategorie_ID", data.FK_SubSubKategorie_ID)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Hersteller_ID", data.FK_Hersteller_ID)
                        newArticleRowID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()      'new article row's id
                    End Using

                    '-- If given article contains images list (artikel_images is a list with pictures associated with article)
                    If Not IsNothing(artikel.collection(articleIndex).artikel_images) Then
                        For Each img In artikel.collection(articleIndex).artikel_images
                            '--Insert article's images if exists
                            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbArticle_Image (Path, FK_Artikel_ID, Position) VALUES (@Path, @FK_Artikel_ID, @Position)", connection)
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                cmd.Connection = connection
                                cmd.Transaction = transaction
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", img.Path)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Artikel_ID", newArticleRowID)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", img.Position)
                                cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                            End Using
                        Next
                    End If

                    '-- If given article contains articles variations list (artikel_variation_attributes is a list with variations associated with article)
                    If Not IsNothing(artikel.collection(articleIndex).artikel_variation_attributes) Then
                        For Each var In artikel.collection(articleIndex).artikel_variation_attributes
                            '--Insert article's images if exists
                            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbArtikel_variation (FK_Variation_Attribute_ID, FK_Artikel_ID, Position) VALUES (@FK_Variation_Attribute_ID, @FK_Artikel_ID, @Position)", connection)
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                cmd.Connection = connection
                                cmd.Transaction = transaction
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Variation_Attribute_ID", var.FK_Variation_Attribute_ID)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Artikel_ID", newArticleRowID)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", var.Position)
                                cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                            End Using
                        Next
                    End If

                    '-- If given article contains additional kategories variations list (artikel_variation_attributes is a list with variations associated with article)
                    '-- In this case list - if exist could be only associated with first article and not for rest (if exist)
                    If articleIndex = 0 Then
                        If Not IsNothing(artikel.collection(articleIndex).artikela_additional_kategories.collection) Then
                            For Each addkat In artikel.collection(articleIndex).artikela_additional_kategories.collection
                                '--Insert article's images if exists
                                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SERT INTO tbAdditionalSubKategories (FK_SubKategorie_ID, FK_SubSubKategorie_ID, FK_Artikel_ID) VALUES (@FK_SubKategorie_ID, @FK_SubSubKategorie_ID, @FK_Artikel_ID)", connection)
                                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                    cmd.Connection = connection
                                    cmd.Transaction = transaction
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_SubKategorie_ID", addkat.FK_SubKategorie_ID)
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_SubSubKategorie_ID", addkat.FK_SubSubKategorie_ID)
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Artikel_ID", newArticleRowID)
                                    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                                End Using
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                transaction.Commit()
            Catch ex As Exception
                result = False
                '-- Roll the transaction back.
                Try
                    transaction.Rollback()
                Catch ex2 As Exception
                    ' This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                    ' on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                    ' a closed connection.
                    'Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType())
                    'Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message)
                End Try

            End Try
        End Using

        Return result
    End Function
#End Region
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it works, but i am not sure if this is how this should be done e.g (i mean placement of trans, conn, rollback) objects

Comment: If you look at the example in the documentation for [SqlTransaction Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will see that the rollback should also be in a Try..Catch. Also, I recommend that you do not use `AddWithValue` - use `Add` and specify the data type (and database column size for strings).

Comment: @Andrew Morton i corrected rollback, i will correct also addwith value, but bsesides it - is it correct or still something missing or wrong placed? Also i made it as function to get info whrther was error or not. Pease check and let me know if ok now.

Comment: and what in case of try catch - i am not sure for line conn.open - if that file how to secure it? I was followed this topic from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You can use `Try..Catch..Finally` instead of Using so that you can handle a failure of `connection.Open()`. As you basically have working code, a better place to ask might be [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - they are usually very thorough. P.S. You have a "SERT" instead of "INSERT" in the `If articleIndex = 0 Then` block.